# Problems while trying to prove that $(r|s)^* = (r^*.s^*)^*$

Tags: formal-languages, regular-expressions

I came across the following equality of regular expressions $$(r|s)^* = (r^*.s^*)^*\,,$$ where $r$ and $s$ are two regular expressions and $.$ denotes concatenation, but I don't know how could I prove it.

**My try:**

I call $L(r)$ the language defined by the regular expression $r$. And I want to use the fact that two regular expressions $r$ and $s$ are equal iff $L(r) = L(s)$.

The LHS can be writen as follows: $$ L((r|s)^{*}) = \bigcup_{i=0}^{+\infty} L(r|s)^{i} = \bigcup_{i=0}^{+\infty} (L(r)^{i} \cup L(s)^{i})\,. $$

The RHS can be writen as follows:
$$ L((r^{*}.s^{*})^{*}) = \bigcup_{i=0}^{+\infty} L((r^{*}.s^{*}))^{i}\,.$$

But I got stuck at this point and I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: What is dot "." in the RHS of this equation?

Comment: @Andremoniy Concatenation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In one direction,
$$
L((r^*s^*)^*) \subseteq L(((r|s)^*(r|s)^*)^*) = L(((r|s)^*)^*) = L((r|s)^*).
$$
In the other direction, $L(r) \subseteq L(r^*s^*)$ and $L(s) \subseteq L(r^*s^*)$ imply that $L(r|s) \subseteq L(r^*s^*)$, and so
$$
L((r|s)^*) \subseteq L((r^*s^*)^*).
$$

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake is in the step
$$
L(r|s)^i = L(r)^i \cup L(s)^i.
$$
Consider for example $r=a$ and $s=b$. Then $L(r|s)^i$ consists of all words (over $\{a,b\}$) of length $i$, whereas the righthand side is $\{a^i,b^i\}$.

Comment: You're right, but this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Well, I'm not planning to do your homework. Perhaps someone else will.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong, this is not homework. I, and some friends of mine, have been fighting this identity for a while without success and that's why I decided to post it in here, hoping to have some help.